# How to pass more than 2 values into SelectList (DropdownList)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the below code which pass 2 values (ProductId and ItemName) to SelectList (Dropdownlist) located on the View.
I need a way to pass 3 values (ProductId, Price, and ItemName).

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductInvoice> ProductInvoices { get; set; }
}


public IActionResult Create()
{
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = _context.Products.Select(c => new SelectListItem
   {
       Value = c.ProductId.ToString() + "-" + c.Price,
       Text = c.ItemName
   });
    
   ViewData["Products"] = items;

   return View();

}
```

Code to generate drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedProducts",new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Products"], "Value", "Text", new { @class = "form-control dropdown-list" }))
```

Comment: What do you need it for? Can you included some explanation, pls?

Comment: @Serge I have 2 models Product and Invoice with their respective views. In Invoice view page, I have a form to save the invoice model and I have a Select dropdownlist that needs to get values from Product model.

Comment: What do you need a price for?

Comment: @Serge I need to display it side by side with the ItemName of Product table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join every property you need by a delimiter and pass it to `Value`. Like this:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = _context.Products.Select(c => new SelectListItem
   {
       Value = String.Join("$", new string[] { c.ProductId.ToString(), c.Price }),
       Text = c.ItemName
   });
```

and when fetching back, you can perform a split with the delimiter. Like this:

```
var myVal = value.Split("$");
string productId = myVal[0];
string price = myVal[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You made almost right thing, only if you want to see the price you have to concat it with Name, not with Id

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
  

var  selectListItems= _context.Products.Select(c => new SelectListItem
   {
       Value = c.ProductId.ToString(),
       Text = c.ItemName+ " - " + c.Price.ToString()
   });
    
var items= new SelectList( selectListItems,"Value", "Text");
ViewData["Products"] = items;

var model=new Product();
   return View( model);

}
```

and fix the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.ProductId, (SelectList) ViewData["Products"],  new { @class = "form-control dropdown-list" }))
```